# How can I filter Integers from a String without filtering all Integers from that String?

Tags: haskell, filter, integer, char

I know the function:

```
numbers xs = filter (\x -> x `elem` [0..9]) xs
```

Example: `numbers "123Text321"` -> `123321`

I don't want to filter all the integers from the String, only the first set (`"123"`).

What would a function need that only takes the first Integers from a string it sees and as soon as it comes to a char it returns the Integers it has found.

Another example: `numbers "b123w321"` -> should return `123`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:takeWhile) combined with [`isDigit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit):

```
import Data.List(takeWhile)
import Data.Char(isDigit)

numbers = takeWhile isDigit
```

---

Your attempt didn't work, because `filter` by its definition traverses the whole list and is unaware of the progress over the traversal (it won't tell that it is supposed to stop after seeing a non-digit).

The other issue is that integers are not chars in Haskell, so you should rather look for `'0'..'9'` instead of `0..9`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I was looking for a solution for so long haha